# XML to JSON using XMLReader Remove Text

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, json

I am converting XMLString to JSONstring using below code. I also tried to convert this XML to a single line by replace newline and whitespaces but nothing change in output.

```
NSError *parseError = nil;
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:&parseError];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:xmlDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if (! jsonData)
{
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Here is my Sample XMLString

```
<component>
        <section ID="id_0b9b2dbb-ac86-4aad-b567-00a78d9e18a7">
           <id root="7d973a3a-d4fa-440c-b9fd-7bf0f9bfc1c4"/>
           <code code="34066-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="Boxed Warning section"/>
           <title>WARNING</title>
           <text>
              <paragraph>Suicidality and Antidepressant Drugs</paragraph>
              <paragraph>
                 <content styleCode="bold">
                    <content styleCode="italics">Use in Treating Psychiatric Disorders:        </content>
                 </content> Antidepressants increased the risk compared to placebo of suicidal thinking and behavior (suicidality) in children, adolescents, and young adults in short-term studies of major depressive disorder (MDD) and other psychiatric disorders. Anyone considering the use of WELLBUTRIN XL<sup>®</sup>* or any other antidepressant in a child, adolescent, or young adult must balance this risk with the clinical need. Short-term studies did not show an increase in the risk of suicidality with antidepressants compared to placebo in adults beyond age 24; there was a reduction in risk with antidepressants compared to placebo in adults aged 65 and older. Depression and certain other psychiatric disorders are themselves associated with increases in the risk of suicide. Patients of all ages who are started on antidepressant therapy should be monitored appropriately and observed closely for clinical worsening, suicidality, or unusual changes in behavior. Families and caregivers should be advised of the need for close observation and communication with the prescriber. WELLBUTRIN XL is not approved for use in pediatric patients. (See <content styleCode="bold"<linkHtml href="#i4i_warnings_id_2dfa5d10-0696-41d8-bc4b-d82cd933a761">WARNINGS: Clinical Worsening and Suicide Risk in Treating Psychiatric Disorders</linkHtml>, <linkHtml href="#i4i_precautions_id_8611ce24-cbea-4cf8-81fe-3efe8c368279">PRECAUTIONS: Information for Patients</linkHtml>, and <linkHtml href="#i4i_precautions_id_8611ce24-cbea-4cf8-81fe-3efe8c368279">PRECAUTIONS: Pediatric Use</linkHtml>.)</content>
</paragraph>
</text>
<effectiveTime value="20100602"/>
</section>
</component>
```

Here is my JSON output:

```
"component" : [
            {
              "section" : {
                "ID" : "Treating",
                "id" : {
                  "text" : "\n               \n                  \n                   ",
                  "root" : "2724b846-267b-4dbb-bd9b-ec4db83617ff"
                },
                "code" : {
                  "code" : "42229-5",
                  "displayName" : "SPL UNCLASSIFIED SECTION",
                  "text" : "\n                     ",
                  "codeSystem" : "2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"
                },
"title" : {
                  "text" : "\n                     Suicidality and Antidepressant Drugs"
                },
                "text" : "\n                  ",
                "effectiveTime" : {
                  "value" : "20120823",
                  "text" : "\n                     "
                }
              },
              "text" : "\n               "
            },
```

And I got this JSON; please help to get proper JSON with accurate data. I am not getting text you can see:

```
"text" : "\n               \n                  \n                   ",
```

Comment: now you got json...what else you want ?

Comment: But i Didn't got JSON with NO data As u Can see in my Question many Text are return blank with also "\n"   and sorry for my bad english.

 "text" : "\n               "

Comment: You JSON output contains values (like "SPL UNCLASSIFIED SECTION") that occur *nowhere* in the XML, so I seriously doubt that this is the real output from the XML to JSON conversion. - Please show the actual input, the actual output, and the **expected output**.

Comment: Hello Martin R I updated my code soryy for that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use [XMLConverter](https://github.com/rsoldatenko/XMLConverter) instead of the XMLReader.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: In JSON output we can see result of incorrect processing text values in XML data. This is how work XMLReader. XMLConverter processes these values ​​correctly. Using XMLConverter little different from the XMLReader and described by link, given in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **KnilOption** instead of NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:xmlDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```